# Sane cubic interpolation for "large" data set, alternative to interp1d?

Tags: scipy, spline

I am working with audio data, so my data sets are usually around 40000 to 120000 points (1 to 3 seconds).  Currently I am using linear interpolation for some task and I would like to use cubic interpolation to improve some results.

I have been using `interp1d` with `kind='linear'` to generate an interpolation function.  This works great and is very intuitive.

However, when I switch to `kind='cubic'`, my computer goes nuts --- the memory starts thrashing, the Emacs window goes dark, the mouse pointer starts moving very slowly, and the harddrive becomes very active.  I assume this is because it's using a lot of memory.  I am forced to (very slowly) open a new terminal window, run `htop`, and kill the Python process.  (I should have mentioned I am using Linux.)

My understanding of cubic interpolation is that it only needs to examine 5 points of the data set at a time, but maybe this is mistaken.

In any case, how can I most easily switch from linear interpolation to cubic interpolation without hitting this apparent brick wall of memory usage?  All the examples of `interp1d` use very few data points, and it's not mentioned anywhere in the docs that it won't perform well for higher orders, so I have no clue what to try next.

Edit: I just tried `UnivariateSpline`, and it's almost what I'm looking for.  The problem is that the interpolation does not touch all data points.  I'm looking for something that generates smooth curves that pass through all data points.

Edit2: It looks like maybe `InterpolatedUnivariateSpline` is what I was looking for.

Comment: Not sure what's up with interp1d, but I've used InterpolatedUnivariateSpline on ~1M point sets in the past successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem in ND interpolation. My solution was to split the data into domains and construct interpolation functions for each domain.

In your case, you can split your data into bunches of 500 points and interpolate over them depending where you are.

```
f1 = [0,...495]
f2 = [490,...,990]
f3 = [985,...,1485]
..
.
.
.
```

and so on.

Also make sure to have an overlap of the intervals of each function. In the example,
the overlap is 5 points. I guess you have to do some experimenting to see what is the optimal overlap.

i hope this helps.